# Two Windows Of The Same Application Do Not Open

Tags: window, ubuntu-14.04, desktop

Is there a way to get two windows of the same application to open in two different desktops?

For instance, if I try to open up a new Firefox window in one desktop when a Firefox window is open in another one, it'll just switch desktops. It won't even open on the same desktop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd> to move programs from one workspace to another